# I need to try and convert some code from a class file to normal actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

Ok so I am creating a flash game, it is a vertical shooter where you have to collect the key to get to the next level. The issue is that for the enemies I have a class file, in this file I have the hit test for the enemies which is the losing condition which works fine and as expected, my problem lies in changing this code into normal actionscript rather than a class to use as a victory condition because as it stands at the moment  when you collect the key it takes you to the victory screen but doesn't reset properly rendering the game unplayable unless reloaded. Any help in converting this would be greatly appreciated

```
if(hitTestObject(_root.mcMain)){
            _root.gameOver = true;
            _root.gotoAndStop('lose');
        }

        if(_root.gameOver){
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
            this.parent.removeChild(this);
        }
    }
    public function removeListeners():void{
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not the class itself, but the fact that you need to reset the game properties in order to start new one.

As far as I can see, your root goes to 'lose' frame. There you can make the reset (reset variables as they were, remove or add children if needed).

There is no way this can be done automatically. You need to know what is wrong and why the game won't start again, in order to fix it.